# Convert List<String> to a Map<String, list> in dart flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dictionary, sharedpreferences, grouped-list

I'm trying to convert a list of string to a map<string, list> so I can display that data in [GroupListView](https://pub.dev/packages/group_list_view)

The data I have looks like this:

```
    [{"surah_no":2,"verse_no":2,"surah_name":"Al-Baqarah","favorite":true}, {"surah_no":2,"verse_no":1,"surah_name":"Al-Baqarah","favorite":true},  {"surah_no":2,"verse_no":3,"surah_name":"Al-Baqarah","favorite":true}, {"surah_no":4,"verse_no":1,"surah_name":"An-Nisa'","favorite":true}, 
{"surah_no":4,"verse_no":5,"surah_name":"An-Nisa'","favorite":true},{"surah_no":12,"verse_no":1,"surah_name":"Yusuf","favorite":true}, {"surah_no":4,"verse_no":7,"surah_name":"An-Nisa'","favorite":true}]
```

The data I need to display in grouplistview:

```
{
    'Al-Baqarah': ['2','1','3'],
    'An-Nisa': ['1','5','7'],
    'Yusuf': [1]

  };
```

I'm getting data from sharedpreferences like this:

```
 SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var lb = await pref.getStringList(('bookmarks_key'));
print(lb);
```

How can I convert this list into a map described above? I can covert the whole list into a map but can we group the map based on a specific parameter 'surah_name' with only 'verse_no's in it? Please help! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Using the [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package, this will produce the desired output:

```
  final data = [
    {"surah_no": 2, "verse_no": 2, "surah_name": "Al-Baqarah", "favorite": true},
    {"surah_no": 2, "verse_no": 1, "surah_name": "Al-Baqarah", "favorite": true},
    {"surah_no": 2, "verse_no": 3, "surah_name": "Al-Baqarah", "favorite": true},
    {"surah_no": 4, "verse_no": 1, "surah_name": "An-Nisa'", "favorite": true},
    {"surah_no": 4, "verse_no": 5, "surah_name": "An-Nisa'", "favorite": true},
    {"surah_no": 12, "verse_no": 1, "surah_name": "Yusuf", "favorite": true},
    {"surah_no": 4, "verse_no": 7, "surah_name": "An-Nisa'", "favorite": true}
  ];

  var result = data
      .groupListsBy((e) => e['surah_name']! as String)
      .map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.map((v) => v['verse_no']! as int).toList()));
```

Here as a working example:
https://dartpad.dev/23715f79111e4ffc8ac3a8f26cc3d3ad

In your desired outcome, you have mixed the verse_no as both `int` and `String`. You'll need to select one of them. I chose `int` now because you wrote them as `int` in the original data.

Comment: Thank you for your help.. But i have to retrieve data from shared preferences as  StringList   so first i have to covert  it to a list of map<string, object>  so the data an be grouped as you mentioned but how am i supposed to convert the list of string data to a list of map?

Comment: I don't undertand what you mean. I have taken the data you have (as you presented in the question), and converted it to the "data you need", as you have written in the question.

Comment: If the "data you have", is not what you have presented in the question. Then you have to update your question with the correct information.

Comment: the actual data coming from the shared preferences looks the same but it's a list of string, we need to convert it to a map first

Comment: So present that in the question! Exactly as it is, and not as an `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` as you have now.